# What are INDEX, REFERENCE, and LOCK TABLE privileges for in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, privileges

As a PHP developer I must set privileges for each database user on my web hosting panel. I read some articles like [which privileges should be set for website database user / client in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030888/which-privileges-should-be-set-for-website-database-user-client-in-mysql)  in Stackoverflow.com, but there are something missed in it I think.

This is what I have to set in my web hosting panel:

[image]

I know about `SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER,GRANT,CREATE TMP TABLES`. But I need to know do I must set or unset the privileges for `INDEX,REFERENCE, and LOCK TABLES`.

What are these 3 last privileges for?

Comment: Any reason you couldn't just google those? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_index https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_references https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_lock-tables

Comment: could you tell me please that do I must enable lock tables privilege always or not? Is it related with MySQL engines like MyISAM or innoDB ?

Answer (score 3):

Information on all the privileges can be found in one lengthy MySQL documentation page.  Here are the three you asked about:

[6.2.2 Privileges Provided by MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html)

> [INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_index)
>
> Enables use of statements that create or drop (remove) indexes. INDEX applies to existing tables. If you have the [CREATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create) privilege for a table, you can include index definitions in the [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) statement.
>
> ---
>
> [REFERENCES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_references)
>
> Creation of a foreign key constraint requires the REFERENCES privilege for the parent table.
>
> ---
>
> [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_lock-tables)
>
> Enables use of explicit [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) statements to lock tables for which you have the [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_select) privilege. This includes use of write locks, which prevents other sessions from reading the locked table.

TLDR:

- `INDEX` allows adding/removing indexes on existing tables.
- `REFERENCES` allows creating foreign key constraints on a table.
- `LOCK TABLES` allows acquiring locks on tables to prevent other sessions from accessing them in particular ways, such as reading or writing.